# r simple shiny table not found a column

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to display a simple table filtering values on a combobox.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(plyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

REGISTROS <- read_xlsx("~/folder/my-file.xlsx", col_names=TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Ociosidade de loja"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("lojaInput",
                  label = "Loja",
                  choices = unique(REGISTROS$loja),
                  selected = 1)

    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("RESULTADO_LISTA")
    )

  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$RESULTADO_LISTA <- renderTable({
    filtered <-
      REGISTROS %>%
      filter(
        loja == input$lojaInput          <=== ERROR LINE = object 'loja' not found
      )
    filtered
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It worked a few times but now it says error `object 'loja' not found`.

The selectInput is using same data and its being correct populated. Also, I can see this values on environment variables...

Here is an example of my XLSX file:

```
weekday        time_entry        mins              loja       group
seg 12         587               Thoughtsphere     Maroon     Morumb
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `filter`?

Comment: `REGISTROS$loja == input$lojaInput` Try this instead

Comment: didn't worked. it took almost 20 seconds to run and returned a table with stranges V1, V2, V3, etc... on all rows

Comment: I'm following this guide: https://deanattali.com/blog/building-shiny-apps-tutorial/

Comment: `output$RESULTADO_LISTA <- renderTable({data<-REGISTROS[REGISTROS$loja==input$lojaInput,]})`

Comment: crazy it worked!!!!!! please post it as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It works perfectly for me.

Edit:
Try and install and load `dplyr` package to deal with your pipes

Comment: it was working at first... so I closed and opened RStudio, cleared environment variables... and then it stopped working...

Comment: You can put the `REGISTROS <- read_xlsx("...` line in the server to ensure that it is loaded in the app everytime, was probably an environment issue

Comment: oooh you got it! on my first lines I was missing a char `library(plyr)`... I've just corrected this and it worked! thanksssss!

Comment: Glad to hear it now works. If you don't mind marking as an answer